# Iterate through nested structs in golang and store values in slice of slice string

Tags: csv, go, struct, slice

I have a nested structs which I need to iterate through the fields and store it in a string slice of slice. Then, output it to a csv file. 
Problem right now is that I am manually accessing each field in the struct and storing it in a slice of slice interface but my actual code has 100 fields so doesn't make sense to call each field manually.
Also, having trouble storing slice of slice interface to csv as I get the following error when writing to a csv file where output is [][]interface{}

```
//      for _, value := range output {
//          err := writer.Write(value) //ERROR: can't use value (type []interface{}) as type []string in argument to writer.Write (build)
//          checkError("Failed write to file", err)
//      }: 
`can't use value (type []interface{}) as type []string in argument to writer.Write (build)`
```

Code:

```
type ApiStruct struct {
    Response []struct { //100 more fields
        A int         `json:"a"`
        B interface{} `json:"b"`
        C bool        `json:"c"`
        D string      `json:"d"`
        E int         `json:"e"`
        F float64     `json:"f"`
        G []string    `json:"g"`
        H bool        `json:"h"`
        I interface{} `json:"i"`
    } `json:"response"`
}

func main() {
    output := api_call()
    for _, value := range output {
        fmt.Println(value)
    }

    // write_file(output)

}

func api_call() (api_data [][]interface{}) {

    api_response := `{
    "response": [{
            "a": 2,
            "b": null,
            "c": false,
            "d": "sdasdas",
            "e": 22,
            "f": -123.2131231,
            "g": ["string1", "string2"],
            "h": true,
            "i": null
        },
        {
            "a": 4,
            "b": null,
            "c": true,
            "d": "sd",
            "e": 22,
            "f": 1223.2131231,
            "g": ["string3", "string4"],
            "h": true,
            "i": null
        }
    ]
  }`

    var d ApiStruct
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(api_response), &d)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    //instead of manually creating the headers or row lables for CSV output, want to know if there's a way to iterate through the key values in the struct
    api_data = append(api_data, []interface{}{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"})

    for _, v := range d.Response {
        api_data = append(api_data, []interface{}{v.A, v.B, v.C, v.D, v.E, v.F, v.G, v.H, v.I})

        /*
            I want to do a for loop on those fields and store values in an array like this or any other way that's easier to store in a csv file.
            Instead of accessing each field individually (v.A, v.B), I want to iterate through the fields because
            I have 100 fields in the struct so doesn't make sense to do v.A, etc 100 times.
            Also, I am not sure if I can range over the interface slice of slice and store it in a csv file. Think it needs to be a string slice of slice [][]string.
            Maybe need to convert interface slice of slice: [][]interface{} to string slice of slice: [][]string

        */

    }

    return
}
```

Please see the link below for more details/comments in the code:

https://play.golang.org/p/OEdi7Dfm_KL

Let me know if anything is unclear! Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There's no code in the actual question, and the playground link has way too much. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question will surely be just as valid with one or two fields.

Comment: added, sorry about that. Let me know if anything is missing

Comment: Does the fact that the source of your data is an API response have any bearing on your actual problem? It seems that you just want to know how to convert your "Response" struct to CSV without having to explicitly refer to each of its fields (A, B, C, etc).

Comment: I don't think my source of data is an issue. The sample response I have provided above is what my API response looks like except its a large JSON blob. I am trying to iterate through the fields in that struct and output to a csv file but not sure if there's a direct way to do that.

Comment: To iterate over the fields of an arbitrary struct you should use the package `reflect`.

Comment: Why don't you use the CSV package itself? (https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/) Also: is that a runtime error or a compile error? If it's a compile error, please post the entire error message (or at least the line that it is causing the error)

Comment: added the error code. I don't think I can write slice of slice interface to a csv file as mentioned in my code. Also, I used the reflect package however, had trouble making it work with nested structs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle the fields of a struct programmatically by using the [`reflect` package](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/), in particular the [`Type`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Type) and [`Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) types. For example:

```
type Foo struct {
  A int
  B bool
  C string
  D float64
  E interface{}
}

func main() {
  f := Foo{1, true, "foo", 3.45, nil}
  t := reflect.TypeOf(f)
  v := reflect.ValueOf(f)

  for i := 0; i < v.NumField(); i++ {
    fmt.Printf("OK: %q -> %#v\n", t.Field(i).Name, v.Field(i))
  }
  // OK: "A" -> 1
  // OK: "B" -> true
  // OK: "C" -> "foo"
  // OK: "D" -> 3.45
  // OK: "E" -> interface {}(nil)
}
```

Using the field names and values as demonstrated above you can generate strings to use with the [`csv` package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/) to generate CSV:

```
func (f Foo) ValueStrings() []string {
  v := reflect.ValueOf(f)
  ss := make([]string, v.NumField())
  for i := range ss {
    ss[i] = fmt.Sprintf("%v", v.Field(i))
  }
  return ss
}

func main() {
  foos := []Foo{Foo{1, true, "foo", 2.34, nil}, Foo{2, false, "bar", 3.45, 1234}}
  w := csv.NewWriter(os.Stdout)

  // Write the CSV header.
  t := reflect.TypeOf(foos[0])
  names := make([]string, t.NumField())
  for i := range names {
    names[i] = t.Field(i).Name
  }
  if err := w.Write(names); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  // Write the CSV rows.
  for _, foo := range foos {
    if err := w.Write(foo.ValueStrings()); err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
  }
  w.Flush()

  if err := w.Error(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }
}
// A,B,C,D,E
// 1,true,foo,2.34,<nil>
// 2,false,bar,3.45,1234
```

Comment: that's great, thank you. Would it be possible to show another example with nested structs as shown in my example? I tried using "reflect" but it didn't quite work with nested structs. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: @shishh03 I don't see any nested structs in your sample code, just `ApiStruct.Response`...

Comment: i'm fairly new to golang so i assumed Response struct inside API struct is called nested struct, my bad :) In your example, you just have Foo struct with different fields inside whereas in my example, I have APIStruct then Response Struct with various fields. I wasn't sure on how to iterate through the fields inside the response struct. I will take the example you provided and experiment with it. Give me few hours!